# How do you use "position:fixed" for fixing an img to a pop-up div?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

So I have a div that is formatted to essentially be a "pop-up" on my website. So on the website, you can scroll. But then when you click an icon to trigger the pop-up, the pop-up itself will allow scrolling (and the scrolling of the website will be disabled). But now I have an image for the "close" button which I want to be fixed in a certain position on (and only on) this div. How would I accomplish this? I don't want the close image to show up at all until the popup is shown, and it disappears when the popup is closed. Currently, I'm using "position:absolute" and it only shows for the popup, and goes away when the popup is closed. But the user has to scroll back up to see the close button again.

Answer (score 2):

Fiddle [Here](http://jsfiddle.net/pk42mqj1/)

Using absolute position is a fine idea in this situation. The key is to make sure that the close button isn't inside the scrollable pane, but on the same level as the wrapper.

HTML

```
<div class="popup">
    <div class="popup-content-wrap">
        <div class="popup-content"></div>
    </div>
    <div class="close">close</div>
</div>
```

CSS

```
.popup {
    position: fixed;
    background-color: blue;
    left: 50px;
    right: 50px;
    bottom: 50px;
    top: 50px;
}
.popup-content-wrap {
    height: 100%;
    width: 100%;    overflow: auto;
}
.popup-content {
    height: 1000px;
}
.close {
    position: absolute;
    bottom: 20px;
    right: 20px;
}
```